# What's wrong with this route?

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $this->router = $this->frontController->getRouter();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':username',
        array(
            'module'     => 'default',
            'controller' => 'view',
            'action'     => 'profile',
            'username'   => ':username'
        )
    );
    $this->router->addRoute('profile', $route);
}
```

What it's supposed to do is match this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/something
```

To:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/view/profile/username/something
```

Which works. The trouble is when I go to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com
```

I get a a long database error which is there basically because it is matched to (and it shouldn't be):

```
http://www.mydomain.com/view/profile
```

But without a username, which is required.

The route is defined in my bootstrap file. What should I do to make it work right?

EDIT:

It seems the problem is with the url helper in my views. What is wrong with these URLs?

```
<?php

echo $this->url(array('module' => 'default',
                      'controller' => 'view',
                      'action' => 'profile',
                      'id' => $this->escape($m->id)),
                null,
                true);

                ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php

echo $this->url(array('module' => 'default',
                      'controller' => 'my-account',
                      'action' => 'write-message'),
                null,
                true);

            ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
'username'   => ':username'
```

This means you're setting the paramater username default value to the string ':username', if you leave it out of the route def, if there is no username it will just ignore this route and move on.

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $this->router = $this->frontController->getRouter();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':username',
        array(
            'module'     => 'default',
            'controller' => 'view',
            'action'     => 'profile',
        )
    );
    $this->router->addRoute('profile', $route);
}
```

Comment: Yes that line is totally useless

Comment: It's not only useless, but the cause of the problem. By having a default value for the username it will always have a value, meaning that this route will always match.

Comment: When I delete that line the www.mydomain.com works fine again but when I go to www.mydomain.com/username I get an error: "username is not specified"

Comment: What version of ZF are you using, it seems to work fine for me?

Comment: I'm using the latest ZF version, but I'm using modular structure if it matters.

Comment: Hi. I have a feeling the problem is with the way I'm using the view helper in my views. Could you please check the example urls I added to my question?